# Hot to set rounded corners when crop image

Tags: android, crop, android-image

I'm implementing an option to select an image on android, crop it and upload to the server

This is the pies of code I use, and I get a rectangle. I would like to have rounded corners when choosing the picture.

```
/**
* starts the image cropper activity
* @param uri of the image to crop
*/
private void cropImage(Uri uri) {
    Logger.get().debug(ILogger.eTag.ACTIVITIES, "CreateGroupActivity:cropImage() invoked.");

    CropImage.activity(uri).
        setAllowFlipping(false).
        setBorderCornerThickness(0f).
        setCropMenuCropButtonTitle(this.getString(R.string.general_Done)).
        setActivityTitle(this.getString(R.string.scale_and_move)).
        setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE).
        setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF).
        setAspectRatio(1,1).
        start(this);
}
```

[image: current view]

Comment: The shape used for the crop would seem to be set by `setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)`. You might want to see what options there are for `CropShape`.

Comment: thats what I dont find...

Comment: I do not know what library you are using. If it is [this one](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper), your only options are `RECTANGLE` and `OVAL`. If neither of those meets your needs, you would need to either find a library that does, modify this library to add your desired option, or write your own image cropping code from scratch.